# Handling a numeric column with some non-numeric entries from a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am in the columns of the excel file, for example, if there are 6 rows of data in this column, if 5 of them are int, and the 6th data is a string, it recognizes the whole column as a string. What should I do so that it does not recognize it as a string?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def check_type(x, t):
    return isinstance(x, t)

file_path = r"C:\Users\Alireza_Molaei\Desktop\Machine1.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
a, b, c = 0, 0, 0

for column in df.columns:
    print(f"column: {column}")
    total_count = df[column].count()
    if total_count > 0:
        int_count = df[df[column].apply(check_type, t=(int, np.int64))][column].count()
        float_count = df[df[column].apply(check_type, t=(float, np.float64))][column].count()
        str_count = df[df[column].apply(check_type, t=str)][column].count()

        a += int_count
        b += float_count
        c += str_count

        print(f"int: {int_count}")
        print(f"float: {float_count}")
        print(f"string: {str_count}")
        print("---------------")
    else:
        print("There is no data in this column")

print(f"int: {a}")
print(f"float: {b}")
print(f"string: {c}")
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: "*What should I do so that it does not recognize it as a string?*" -> it's impossible to set the dtype to numeric if you have non-numeric objects in the column

Comment: That's not an Excel file. `CSV` is a simple text file with Values Separated by Commas. What does the file actually contain? What do you want to do with data that can't be converted? You can't convert `Banana` to a number. You can tell `read_csv` to convert such values to NaN though.

Answer (score 1):

If the raw data contains non-numeric data, of course pandas cannot automatically make that column numeric. What would it be supposed to do with the strings?

You have to tell pandas what to do with any "dirty" columns, for example set records that cannot be converted to `np.NaN` (if that's what you prefer instead of strings). You can use `pd.to_numeric` and `coerce` errors.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Tom', 50000], ['Anna', 'foo']], columns=['name', 'salary'])
df['salary'] = pd.to_numeric(df['salary'], errors='coerce')

print(df)
   name   salary
0   Tom  50000.0
1  Anna      NaN
```

So let it read the data from `.csv` as it wants. You may not want to code your "conversion" rule in your reader function - it might not be the most transparent place in case you need to debug/change something later. Why not just read everything, let pandas choose the type. And if you have mixed columns that are of type `object`, but you feel they should be numeric, do the cleanup separately yourself/in a "cleansing" function by telling pandas what to do with non-numeric data (e.g., set to `NaN`)